# adding total columns value in datagrid view

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview and  3 textboxes and datagrid view is filled up with these columns, court fee, and claim amt 
I need no of  rows in datagridview,total courtfee and total claim amount I have sorted the total court and no of requests but stuck with total claim amount.

```
no of rows in datagridviews, = 4 which should be in this format  (00004)
total court fee = total court fee value   = 60 (15 each requests) ( 000006000)
total claim amount = 4000 ( which should be in this format 0000004000) but i get this value ( 0000001000).
```

This is my code:

```
decimal requests = 0;
        decimal CFee = 0;
        decimal CLAIMAMT = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {


            string strrequests = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
            while (strrequests.Length < 5)
                strrequests = "0" + strrequests;
            textBox2.Text = strrequests.ToString();
            //string strCFee = (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["CFee"].Value).ToString();
            string strCFee = ((Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value) / 100) *       dataGridView1.RowCount).ToString();
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                strCFee = "0" + strCFee;
            while (strCFee.Length < 9)
                strCFee += "0";
            textBox3.Text = strCFee;
            // string strCLAIMAMT = (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value).ToString();
            string strCLAIMAMT = ((Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value) / 100)).ToString();
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                strCLAIMAMT = "0" + strCLAIMAMT;
            while (strCLAIMAMT.Length < 10)
                strCLAIMAMT += "0";
            textBox4.Text = strCLAIMAMT;
        }    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd look into [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for lopping through gridviews.

Second, I'd look into [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830.aspx)  to add zeroes to your string.

To answer your question,  in your loop you'll want something like this to get the total claim amount, rows and fee:

```
    decimal requests = 0;
    decimal CFee = 0;
    decimal CLAIMAMT = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {           
        CLAIMAMT +=  Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value); 
        CFee +=  Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value); 
        requests++;
    }     


    lblClaimAmountTotal.Text = CLAIMAMT.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
    lblCFeeTotal.Text = CFee.ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
    lblRequestTotal.Text = requests.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```